# dummy question for calculation in C#

Tags: c#

I want to calculate lets say 100 * 14.5% in C#
How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Clearly the only *correct* answer is 14.5

Comment: You missed the second operand to `%`. I'd suggest 49.5

Comment: The close Nazis strike again.  This IS a real question and it even has real answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = 100.0 * .145;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually a C# question, but more of a basic math question:

```
100 * 0.145
```

Comment: He could be looking for the proper syntax, but I agree, based on what the OP wrote, it looks like he has the correct operator.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:  100 * .145